# Sort Grouped Columns in AdvancedDatagrid

Tags: apache-flex, sorting, advanceddatagrid

I#m looking for a solution to sort all grouped colums in advancedDatagrid. It should be the same behavior like clicking in a columns head.

Please note, i'm not looking for a solution to sort the fields IN a the grouping. There is working solution named compareFunction.

But I'm not able to sort the two rows in my picture by column "Einnahmen". Sorry for the german word.
Do you have an Idea?
[image]

Thank you
Frank

Comment: Is there a reason they can't click on the column header itself?

Comment: i want to start my application clean and sorted. Thats the reason. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, i the creationComplete Handler i sort my dataProvider of adg and the adg comes up clean with the sorted column "einnahmen". But if i expand one node, the column "monat" contains all month from 1 to 12. The row should be sorted too. Is there a chance to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to sort the values in the child nodes or the parent for the "Monat" column?

Comment: truth be told, i have no idea how i can make a different between sorting the parent or the child. It would be great if you have a idea. Thank you - Frank

Comment: @Frank, The only way I can think of doing this is by using a cursor and going through your data collection line by line and sorting the children through some custom code. The `AdvancedDataGrid` can't handle that kind of functionality out of the box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking to start the application with sorted columns, you need to simulate a header click upon creation/dateprovider update.

Try this:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="adg"
  updateComplete="adg.dispatchEvent(new AdvancedDataGridEvent(AdvancedDataGridEvent.HEADER_RELEASE, false, true, 3, 'Einnahmen'))">
    <mx:columns>
        ...
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Einnahmen" sortDescending="true" />
    </mx:columns>
</mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

I haven't tried this for grouped collections but let me know how this works.

Comment: Hey, this was new for me. Thank you. Unfortunately, it won't work. I receive an errormessage like this: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference from AdvancedDataGridBaseEx. Sorry. But good idea.

Comment: The dataProvider has probably not been initialized is all

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
I didn't know you were building your `dataProvider` through ActionScript. You should still be able to run the `Sort` on your collection after you've finished putting it together though.

Another option would be to extend the `AdvancedDataGrid` component and override the `set dataProvider` method to sort the data as soon as you bind it. Here's [an example another developer provided](http://www.curiousfind.com/blog/78) ([source](http://www.curiousfind.com/tutorials/sitemaptutorial/srcview/index.html)) for the `Tree` control, but the same concept could probably be used on the `AdvancedDataGrid`.

*Original answer:*

Assuming you're just trying to sort the top level "Einnahmen" values (which it looks like you are from your screenshot), I would manually sort your `dataProvider` after data is returned from whatever service you're using to get your data.

Here's a very basic example of manually sorting your collection.

```
[Bindable] public var MyDataList:ArrayCollection;
private var einnahmenSortField:SortField = new SortField("Einnahmen", true, false);
private var theSort:Sort = new Sort();

// Called after data is returned from the remote service call to sort the data
public function SetMyDataList(returnedList:ArrayCollection):void
{
  MyDataList = returnedList;

  if (theSort == null)
  {
    theSort = new Sort();
    theSort.fields = [einnahmenSortField];
  }

  MyDataList.sort = this.theSort;   
  MyDataList.refresh();
}
```

To convert it to `HierarchicalData` for use in your `AdvancedDataGrid`, just create a new instance of `HierarchicalData` and assign it to your `AdvancedDataGrid` like this:

```
var hd:HierarchicalData = new HierarchicalData(myDataList);
hd.childrenField = "MyChildField";
myAdvancedDataGrid.dataProvider = hd;
```

Comment: hmm, works also not. At the end, I can't convert the ArrayCollection to HirachicalData, because I have to group all the Data in AS. I think, while building the grouping, the sorting goes anway. damn

Comment: This is a SQLLite-Air Application. The Data are received from SQLite-Database in a flat format. Lets say 1000 entries as a array. Each entry has a flat format like Vertrag:"data", name:"data" monat:"data" einahmen:"data". in english words: ContractNumber, CustomerName, month, earned.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set the 'sortExpertMode="true"' in the AdvancedDataGrid tag? Please find the sample code below:

```
  <mx:AdvancedDataGrid height="318"
                     id="dataSetsDG"
                     allowMultipleSelection="false"
                     folderClosedIcon="{null}"
                     folderOpenIcon="{null}"
                     defaultLeafIcon="{null}"
                     left="28"
                     top="162"
                     rowCount="11"
                     width="70%"
                     displayItemsExpanded="true"
                     sortExpertMode="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

I used 'HierarchicalData' as the dataprovider for the AdvancedDataGrid.I also created the HierarchialData from the ArrayCollection, the sort order was maintained and it works like a charm.You can give it a try!
Please find the Actionscript code and a sample screenshot.

[image: Advanced Datagrid]

```
    public function createHierarchialResultVO(results:ArrayCollection):ArrayCollection
    {
        [ArrayElementType("ResultsVO")]
        var dpHierrarchy:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

        for each(var result:Result in results)
        {
            var resultVO:ResultsVO= new ResultsVO();
            resultVO.resultName = result.resultName;
            resultVO.runDate = result.runDate.toString();
            resultVO.type="header";

            var childrens:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            for each(var processDetails:ProcessDetails in result.details)
            {
                var children:ResultsVO= new ResultsVO();
                children.files =result.fileCount;
                children.status=result.status;
                children.type="result";
            }
            resultVO.children =children;
            dpHierrarchy.addItem(resultVO);
        }
        return dpHierrarchy;            
    }
```

Comment: wow, i try it tomoorow morning. Thank you. It would be kindly to add some comments for knowing, what do you do why. But tomorrow i get deeper into the code, i hope it will be selfexplaning. Thanks cu

Comment: Allright. Unfortunately, my data hasn't this structure. So i have no chance, to make a different between sorting a parant or sorting a child. But thank you for your code in every case.